# Mean value property in Lie groups

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, laplace-transform, harmonic-functions

On $\mathbb{R}^n$, two equivalent definitions of harmonic functions are

1. $\Delta f=0$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator.
2. $f$ satisfies the mean value property, i.e. 
   $$
   f(x)=\frac{1}{vol(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}fdV
   $$
   for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Does the same equivalency hold in Lie groups? that is, are there analogues  definitions for Laplace operator, metric, and volume, for which $\Delta f=0$ is equivalent to mean value property?

Thanks!